# How to select a tags and scrape href value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

I am having trouble getting hyperlinks for tennis matches listed on a webpage, how do I go about fixing the code below so that it can obtain it through print?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
response = requests.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/results/tennis/?year=2022&month=11&day=02")
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

print(soup.findAll('a href'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

Select your elements more specific and use `set comprehension` to avoid duplicates:

```
set('https://www.betexplorer.com'+a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href^="/tennis"]:has(strong)'))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/results/tennis/?year=2022&month=11&day=02')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

set('https://www.betexplorer.com'+a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href^="/tennis"]:has(strong)'))
```

##### Output

```
{'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-men-singles/m15-new-delhi-2/sinha-nitin-kumar-vardhan-vishnu/tOasQaJm/',
 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-women-doubles/w25-jerusalem/mushika-mao-mushika-mio-cohen-sapir-nagornaia-sofiia/xbNOHTEH/',
 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-men-singles/m25-jakarta-2/barki-nathan-anthony-sun-fajing/zy2r8bp0/',
 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-women-singles/w15-solarino/margherita-marcon-abbagnato-anastasia/lpq2YX4d/',
 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-women-singles/w60-sydney/lee-ya-hsuan-namigata-junri/CEQrNPIG/',
 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/itf-men-doubles/m15-sharm-elsheikh-16/echeverria-john-marrero-curbelo-ivan-ianin-nikita-jasper-lai/nsGbyqiT/',...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to

```py
print([a['href'] for a in soup.findAll('a')])
```

See a full tutorial here: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/get-links-from-webpage/

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)